# Installing ConTeXt on windows machine

Tags: context, windows

I would like to install ConTeXt MKIV on my windows machine. I tried to follow the seemingly official docs for this [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Installation), but it looks like all the links to the windows x64 zip files are broken.

Is there an up to date, functional page for installation of ConTeXt on Windows?

Comment: It more seems that your browser things the ZIP i dangerous, perhaps due to the download not using https. Which browser are you using?

Comment: If I explicitly tell my Firefox that download is ok, then I get the ZIP

Comment: Ah... you're right. I just tried it with Edge and it worked (I was using Chrome)...

Comment: Allright, so I downloaded and ran `install.bat` and `setpath.bat` from powershell. Both seemed to run without errors, but `context` is not yet recognized as a command line program. Should I make a new question for that?

Comment: Probably. Did you start a new powershell?