# Trouble installing ConTeXt on windows machine

Tags: context

I was able to download and extract the context installation from this page thanks to @daleif's comment provided in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621311/installing-context-on-windows-machine?noredirect=1#comment1551025_621311).

I then extracted the archive in `C:\context` and ran `install.bat` and `setpath.bat`. Both seemed to run OK. Here's some of the final output generated by `install.bat`:

```
mtx-install     | tex/texmf            :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
mtx-install     | tex/texmf-context    :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
mtx-install     | tex/texmf-win64      :    0 files with         0 bytes installed
mtx-install     | 
mtx-install     | ConTeXt LMTX with LuaMetaTeX is still experimental and when you get a crash this
mtx-install     | can be due to a mismatch between Lua bytecode and the engine. In that case you can
mtx-install     | try the following:
mtx-install     | 
mtx-install     |   - wipe the texmf-cache directory
mtx-install     |   - run: mtxrun --generate
mtx-install     |   - run: context --make
mtx-install     | 
mtx-install     | When that doesn't solve the problem, ask on the mailing list (ntg-context@ntg.nl).
mtx-install     | 
mtx-install     | update, done


Updating installer:

        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.

When you want to use context, you need to initialize the tree with:

  C:\context\setpath.bat

You can associate this command with a shortcut to the cmd prompt. Alternatively
you can add

  C:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin

to your PATH variable. If you run from an editor you can specify the full path
to mtxrun.exe:

  C:\context\tex\texmf-win64\bin\mtxrun.exe --autogenerate --script context --autopdf ...

The following settings were used:

  server   : lmtx.contextgarden.net,lmtx.pragma-ade.com,lmtx.pragma-ade.nl
  instance : install-lmtx
  extras   : 
  ownpath  : C:\context\
  platform : win64
```

I restarted powershell, downloaded the [hello world tex file](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/images/2/22/Hello-world.tex) and tried to compile as follows:

`context test.tex`

But powershell did not recognize the command and I got the following output which I had to force-exit out of, and which indicates `context` has not been added as a command line executable:

```
cmdlet Context at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
```

Has anything gone wrong with my installation? How can I get context to work on my windows machine?

## Edit

In response to @Ulrike Fischers comment:

```
C:\context > echo $env:path
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\921479\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Editor
C:\context > .\setpath.bat
C:\context > context

cmdlet Context at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name:
C:\context > echo $env:path
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\921479\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Tracker Software\PDF Editor
```

Comment: Are you sure the command to run `context` is actually called `context`?  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461358/whats-the-right-way-to-run-context

Comment: you should not restart powershell. the setpath batch file only sets the path for one session. You could add the path as suggested in the text to your path environment variable, then it will be permanent.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit to the original question. Running `context` right after `.\setpath.bat ` doesn't really fix this behavior

Comment: @UlrikeFischer does my edit make sense? Or should I provide additional details?

Comment: try `where context` after setting the path. And perhaps try first in the normal command line not in the powershell

Comment: Ok, so on regular `cmd` it works, but I really want to get this thing up and running in `powershell` because, well, `cmd` is garbage compared to it. 

Is there any way I can adapt the `setpath.bat` to work in powershell?

Comment: Ok I just got it working by manually updating my environment variables.